# Can MSSQL server (v. 16) save a returned sql-query in json-format into another db-table

Tags: sql-server

server experts,

can anyone say if MSSQL server (v. 16) can save a returned sql-query in json-format into another db-table (into just one db-field as json string)? After that the json- as a string is to be queried from this table-field.

If that is possible, how to implement it?

Comment: Are you talking about all SQL commands ran on the server (audit-like)or are you talking about generating a SQL command and manually saving it? Also, why save it in JSON if it is just a single string?

Comment: The result of a query that uses `FOR JSON` is already a string and can be treated as such for purposes of including it in another query (e.g. `SELECT (SELECT ... FOR JSON ..) AS SingleValue`). But it's not at all clear if that's what your question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not directly, you need a little bypass. Consider the following:

```
WITH CTE (JSON_Col) AS -- end previous statement with semi-colon

(
   SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
   FROM TableA FOR JSON AUTO
)

SELECT JSON_Col INTO ResultsTable FROM CTE
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant it in the sense that you cannot insert the inner part directly. We are by-passing that with the cte. (just as a matter of speach)

Comment: Or you could use a subquery. That's how SQL works. You create the results with `SELECT` and insert them with the `INSERT` statement. BTW why create a new table?

Comment: No, it's not. SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC INTO NewTable is perfectly valid. It's the FOR JSON Auto statement that makes is different.

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM TableA FOR JSON AUTO) AS JSON_Col INTO ResultsTable` will do just fine. You can't stick the `INTO` in the inner query, that's true. Whether to use a CTE or a subquery is a matter of taste and convenience.

Comment: I want to thank all who gave their replies to this issue - I have not had yet time to test these solutions and suggestions but soon I will and make my further questions then after that.

Comment: Both provided solutions worked equally well and solved my problem, thank you experts once more!